# Web Server running on rebooted ec2 instance, address is not resolving correctly

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, wordpress, apache2

I had an issue with my Apache web server running on an AWS EC2 Instance and I had to reboot. Once the server came up I started Apache, but was unable to access the server. I know that the public dns entry and ip address get reassigned via dchp, but when I access the new address, it redirects me to the old address and doesn't load.

I've tried doing an NSLOOKUP, flushing dns, and doing a traceroute with no success, as well as checking the web server config and checking the access log to ensure nothing was being logged. I checked the server via ssh and the correct ports are open and the process is running. I checked the network analyzer when I tried to hit the right address and saw it was doing a 301 redirect. Has anyone else encountered a similar situation, and are there any other troubleshooting steps that I can take?

EDIT:
Unfortunately I can only add 2 pictures with my current reputation. Please see the links below.

[curl command via ssh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17smO.png)
[AWS console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0z8X.png)

Comment: If my answer solved your problem you don't need those images. If it didn't you should reply to my answer and give more information.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was a two part problem it seems. I assigned an Elastic IP address, but the address stored in the Wordpress DB was still pointing to the old address, so once that was updated, everything was working as expected.

Comment: Wordpress doesn't typically need the IP address of the server it runs on.

Comment: @Tim I suspect "IP address" actually means "hostname that looks like an IP address."

Comment: Michael is correct, sorry. The host name is comprised of ec2 followed by the public IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your public IP can change if you stop then start the server, but it should survive a restart.

The best solution here is to assign your instance an [Elastic IP Address](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html).

If you want any further help you'll need to share a lot more information. Start by editing your post to include a screenshot of the EC2 console that shows the public IP, the matching security group, and a curl from the machine showing Apache is working locally.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. I did a start and stop of the ec2 instance, which triggered a change in the public IP and public DNS. Would an Elastic IP Address still be the solution for that situation? I'll also update the question to include more information

Comment: Yes, you should use an elastic IP and yes it will solve this problem for you. They're free while you're using them, but you get charged a small amount if you leave them unallocated.